# OrderBy in LINQ to Entity

Tags: linq-to-entities, sql-order-by

I have this LINQ query and want to add a second orderby.

```
var clients = from c in context.clients
                                  orderby c.clientname
                                  select new { c, orders = c.orders};
```

So after this i have an alfabetical list of clients with unorderd ORDERS.
I also want to OrderBy on ORDERS.ORDERNUMBER

If possible I want to do all of this in one query.

How to? 
Please

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - what are you expecting the result to be? Still a list of clients, or a list of orders?

Comment: yes one odered list of clients each with an ordered list of orders

Comment: Okay, answered. You're wanting to order a different sequence, which is what was confusing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
var clients = from c in context.clients
              orderby c.clientname
              select new { c, orders = c.orders.OrderBy(o => o.OrderNumber) };
```

Comment: Jon you are my hero for today.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tuple<int, string>[] x = new Tuple<int,string>[] {
    new Tuple<int, string>(0, "a"),   
    new Tuple<int, string>(1, "b"),
    new Tuple<int, string>(2, "b"),
    new Tuple<int, string>(2, "a"),
    new Tuple<int, string>(3, "e")
};

var ordered = (from p in x orderby p.Item1 select p).ThenBy(a => a.Item2);

foreach (var item in ordered)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Item1.ToString() + " - " + item.Item2);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```